# Cannot set EditText? Issue From dialog in a fragment - Strange - Android Java

Tags: java, android, fragment

I've come across an issue which I've never had before. I have a `Fragment` containing a button. This button (`ViewBookingButton`) shows a popup dialog. When the dialog opens I would like to set a string in an `EditText` (`AllBooking`). Unfortunately it crashes and shows `NullPointerExecption`. What is going wrong? Here is my code:

```
ViewBookingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder ViewBookingHelpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        ViewBookingHelpBuilder.setTitle("view booking:");

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View DialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_booking, null);
        ViewBookingHelpBuilder.setView(DialogLayout);

        TextView AllBooking = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.AllBooking);

        AllBooking.setText("Hello World");//WHEN I REMOVE THIS THE DIALOG WORKS


        ViewBookingHelpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override   
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
             {                   
             }
        });


        AlertDialog helpDialog = ViewBookingHelpBuilder.create();
        helpDialog.show();

            }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
 TextView AllBooking = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.AllBooking);
```

to

```
 TextView AllBooking = (TextView)DialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.AllBooking);
```

`TextView` belongs to the inflated layout and `findViewById looks for the view in the current view hierarchy.